# Cohomology groups of a torus minus a finite number of disjoint open disks

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have to compute the De Rham cohomology groups of a torus with $g$ holes minus $n$ "small" (in some sense) open disks. Fix $n=g=1$ since I suppose that once this basic case is understood everything is fine.
I want to use Mayer-Vietoris but I'm new to this kind of exercises and I'm not even able to identify (visualize them is the problem) two suitable open sets. Maybe it is easier to choose such sets on the "square" $Q=([0,1] \times [0,1]) \setminus D$ where $D$ is a small disk and *then* pass to the quotient, but am I even allowed to do so?

Any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using 
$\chi(A\cup B)= \chi (A)+\chi (B)-\chi (A\cap B)$, we get

$\chi (T) =\chi (T \setminus \cup _{i=1}^n D_i) + \sum \chi (D_i) = 0$

And $\chi (D)=1$

We get $\chi (T \setminus \cup _{i=1}^n D_i)=-n$

As $b_2(T \setminus \cup _{i=1}^n D_i)=0$, we get $1-b_1((T \setminus \cup _{i=1}^n D_i))=-n$

$b_1(T \setminus \cup _{i=1}^n D_i)=n+1$

The coefficients are taken where you want, $\bf Z$ for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do you know that the top cohomology has dimension $0$ since this manifold has a boundary  ?

Comment: Precisely, for  manifold with boundary the top cohomology has dimension 0, because it has the same homotopy type than a CW complex of dimension $n-1$, here a graph. The problem is to compute the $b_1$ of this graph, and as usual it is much easier to compute the Euler characteristic.

Comment: Unfortunately, we did not discuss CW complexes in our class.. I would be grateful if you can provide a different  explanation !